# Insert a new row to table with select dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, laravel-5.7

Logic: select an item from the dropdown list and put it in the table with four more input "Item, Quantity, Price, Total".
in the Item column must show the selected item. every selected item has quantity and price.in the Total column must show the sum of quantity and price.
and it should insert items as many items as the user wants.
I'm really confused about this, haven't done this kind of work befor.
any assistance would be really appreciated.

this is the select item dropdown

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label class="control-label col-md-3">Items
         <span class="required"> * </span>
     </label>
     <div class="col-md-5">
       <select class="form-control select2me" name="item_id" id="selectitems">
          <option value=""></option>
             @foreach($items as $item)
              <option value="{{ $item->id }}"> {{ $item->name }} ({{ $item->cname}}) </option>
             @endforeach
       </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

table

```
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamicTable">  
            <tr>
                <th>Item</th>
                <th>Qty</th>
                <th>Price</th>
                <th>Total</th>
            </tr>

        </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Method : Using JavaScript 
Add the following function to the   of the file. 
Using javascript we are adding an event listener to  so when the item is selected, the function is called. 
The function when called accesses the item value and makes a new row with desired values.

```
window.onload=function() {
var select_element = document.getElementById("selectitems");
select_element.onchange = function() {
    var item = this.value;
    var table = document.getElementById("dynamicTable");
    // create new row at desired position
    var row = table.insertRow(-1) // use -1 to insert in last position (can also use 0 to insert in first place and so on)
    // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the <tr> element:
    var cell_item = row.insertCell(0);
    var cell_quanitity = row.insertCell(1);
    // add rest of the columns here
    // Add some text to the new cells:
    cell_item.innerHTML = item;
    cell_quantity.innerHTML = "3";
    // similarly set text for rest of the columns here
} 
}
```

Hope this helped